# need help with androids sql query

Tags: java, android, sql

I have an error in that m

```
     String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());

     Cursor myCursor=db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID,MONEY_FIGURE,SPENDING_DETAILS,DATE}
             , KEY_ROWID , null,  null,  DATE+"="+currentDateTimeString,  KEY_ROWID, null);
```

The query function by the androids api:

```
query(boolean distinct, String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)
```

What I am trying to do here is to say. give me all the data based on where the date equals 
currentDateTimeString .

But I get an error on that statement..
dont ask me what the error is..when i remove the call to the method holding that query statement the error doesnt appear..so i guess it is an sqlexception

SOLVED MY ME:

```
 Cursor myCursor=db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID,MONEY_FIGURE,SPENDING_DETAILS,DATE}
         ,DATE+"='"+currentDateTimeString+"'"  , null,  null, null ,  KEY_ROWID, null);
```

I am trying to do this

```
SELECT MONEY_FIGURE,SPENDING_DETAILS,DATE
FROM SpendingManagmentTable
WHERE Date=@ currentDateTimeString
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column type is not number then have to use with ''

date='1/1/2011' not date=1/1/2011

```
Cursor c =  db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {{KEY_ROWID,MONEY_FIGURE,SPENDING_DETAILS,DATE},DATE+"='"+currentDateTimeString+"'", null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: still the mistake is thrown..didnt you see that it is a string.. how do i debug an android application..i tried with cat log nothing appears